# How to Find a target value in a column?

Tags: vba, excel

Haha! I'll stump you yet Excel gurus. ;-D

I want to set a selection range boundary based on some delimiting text.

If I do Cells.Find the entire worksheet is searched and the multiple instances are found.
The one I want found is likely the 3rd or 4th instance of the delimiter. Actually it is in a specific column, B. However it is a non-contiguous range and the actual search start in the column is a few hundred cells down.

How do I search within that column and set my reusable range begin variable, set to the delimiter cell (not including the delimiter cell)?
I've tried this:

```
Dim selectionStart As Range, selectionEnd As Range
Dim currentCell As Range, dataRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Range, insertRows As Range, destinationCell As Range

Range("b1", Range("b65536").End(xlUp)).Select

Set selectionStart = Selection.Find(What:="<-RANGE START->", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
    :=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
   xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

It selects the range but doesn't set the variable.

I'm trying out all these things annoyingly big so I can see what they do without too much eyestrain. Elegance is not required.

TIA

Comment: Maybe it doesn't set the variable because it can't find what you're looking for? It would help to show a little more of your code, following the call to `Find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim selectionStart As Range, selectionEnd As Range
Dim currentCell As Range, dataRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Range, insertRows As Range, destinationCell As Range
Dim rngtoSearch As Range
Dim foundValue As Variant
Dim foundAddress As String
Dim foundRow As Long

With sheetWhatever 'change to whatever sheet codename required
    Set rngtoSearch = .Range("b1", .Range("b65536").End(xlUp))

    Set selectionStart = rngtoSearch.Find(What:="<-RANGE START->", LookIn _
        :=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
       xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'check it actually found a range
    If Not selectionStart Is Nothing Then
        'If found set the variable
        foundValue = selectionStart.Value 'set as value
        foundAddress = selectionStart.Address 'set as address string
        foundRow = selectionStart.Row ' set as row
    End If

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Tim Williams pointed it out, and I figured it out after I posted.
There was a preliminary Macro that I had not run yet.

Works now. Once again, I have failed to stump you.
And this one was an involuntary trick question....